# how to install multiple instances of the same application using msi Installer

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer

I am using visual studio set up project  to create my msi Installer.My requirement is to create multiple instances of the application using this same installer without changing version number/product code.

Is there is any way to do it without using Wix/Installshield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, if you want to use MSI and install multiple instances, you need instance Transforms (i.e. changing the Product Code) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369528(v=VS.85).aspx

Why don't you want to change the product code using and instance transform?

Answer (score 5):

Windows Installer doesn't support multiple instances with the same Product Code and Upgrade Code. Product Version can remain the same. A different instance is actually considered a different product.

Multiple instances are not supported by Visual Studio setup project files and they are not easy to implement. The general approach is this:

- Create a [MST transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) for each instance. Each transform should use a different Product Code and different component GUIDs.
- Write a custom EXE bootstrapper which can [apply these transforms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490766.aspx) to your original MSI.
- Optionally find a way to include the transforms and MSI in a single EXE setup file.

Other authoring tools do offer support for multiple instances, but the instances number is usually limited. It all depends on how many transforms you create.